# How do I pass a parameter which is defined as an interface<generictype>?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics

I am trying to use a method with a parameter which is an interface with what seems like a generic type in angle brackets, but I've no idea how to pass my value into it.

The method is defined something like:

```
public static class Settings {

    public static void UpdateSetting<TType>(ISetting<TType> setting)
    {
        // Do its thing
    }
}
```

Now I try to call this by using my code such as this:

```
Settings.UpdateSetting<MyParticularSettingType>(new MyParticularSettingType { Value = "settingvalue"});
```

with, elsewhere...

```
public class MyParticularSettingsType : Setting<string>
```

and...

```
public abstract class Setting<TType> : ISetting<TType>
```

But on the parameter, I get an error.

> Cannot convert from MyNameSpace.MyParticularSettingType to SettingsNamespace.ISetting<MyNameSpace.MyParticularSettingType>

I've tried casting it, while that gets rid of the compile error, it throws an exception at run-time

> Unable to cast object of type 'MyNameSpace.MyParticularSettingType' to type 'SettingsNamespace.ISetting`1[MyNameSpace.MyParticularSettingType]

```
Settings.UpdateSetting((ISetting<MyParticularSettingType>)(new MyParticularSettingType { Value = "settingvalue" }));
```

What exactly am I supposed to be doing?

Comment: MyParticularSettingsType is of type ISetting<String>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling the method this way.

```
Settings.UpdateSetting<string>(new MyParticularSettingType { Value = "settingvalue"});
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Also accidentally discovered that `Settings.UpdateSetting(new MyParticularSettingType { Value = "settingvalue"});` works...

Comment: @colmde Yes. You might want to take a look here about this behaviour. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975364/c-sharp-generic-method-without-specifying-type